# .net c sharp LINQ : return Object utilization

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is my LINQ statement

```
var Query = from products in pLDataContex.Products
            where (products.Id == p)
            select new OrderProductMapping
            {
                OrderId = insertedOrderId,
                ProductId = p,
                ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt32(products.Price.ToString()),
                ProductQuantity = products.Quantity,
                ProductAmount = Convert.ToInt32(products.Price * products.Quantity)
            } into x
            select x;
```

what I try to do is get some details from Product table (Like price and Quantity) and create a OrderProductMapping Object So that I can use that object's Value to user letter on in the Application .

But from Variable "Query" How can I retrieve values ?
any Idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you can make your query simpler by removing the "into x select x" at the end. Just leave it at the `select new ...` part. You can also remove the brackets in the `where` clause.

I'd also suggest simple casts for the ProductPrice and ProductAmount - in particular, converting the product price into a string before parsing sounds like a bad idea to me. What are the types of `Price` and `Quantity` in the first place?

Finally, it's generally a good idea to make the range variable name singular, as it's only applied to one item at a time:

```
var query = from product in pLDataContex.Products
            where product.Id == p
            select new OrderProductMapping
            {
                OrderId = insertedOrderId,
                ProductId = p,
                ProductPrice = (int) product.Price,
                ProductQuantity = product.Quantity,
                ProductAmount = (int) (product.Price * products.Quantity)
            };
```

Now Query will be typed to `IEnumerable<OrderProductMapping>`. Are you expecting a single result? If so, use one of:

- [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) - will throw if it doesn't get exactly one result
- [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) - will throw if it doesn't get any results, will ignore any result after the first
- [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) - will throw if it gets more than one results, but return null if it doesn't get any
- [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) - will return null if it gets any results, will ignore any result after the first

I would suggest a call which will make the system throw in all the situations (and only the situations) which indicate a programming error. If it's expected that the product may not be found (e.g. the user has entered the ID) then `SingleOrDefault()` is probably appropriate, assuming that `Id` is a primary key. You'd write:

```
OrderProductMapping mapping = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

Then react appropriate based on whether `mapping` is null or not.

EDIT: Reacting to the comment, the easiest way round this is to use an anonymous type, fetch the result of the query, and then build your desired result type from that:

```
var query = from product in pLDataContex.Products
            where product.Id == p
            select new 
            {
                OrderId = insertedOrderId,
                ProductId = p,
                ProductPrice = (int) product.Price,
                ProductQuantity = product.Quantity,
                ProductAmount = (int) (product.Price * product.Quantity)
            };

var anonMapping = query.SingleOrDefault();
if (anonMapping != null)
{
    OrderProductMapping mapping = new OrderProductMapping
    {
        OrderId = anonMapping.OrderId,
        ProductId = anonMapping.ProductId,
        ProductPrice = anonMapping.ProductPrice,
        ProductQuantity = anonMapping.ProductQuantity,
        ProductAmount = anonMapping.ProductAmount
    };
}
```

Note that this won't have general entity behaviour - if you modify the mapping, you'll have to explicitly save any changes to the database. I can't see that being an issue in this case though.

Another alternative is to use `AsEnumerable` to perform the projection in process:

```
var query = pLDataContex.Products
               .Where(product => product.Id == p)
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Select(product => new OrderProductMapping
                       {
                           OrderId = insertedOrderId,
                           ProductId = p,
                           ProductPrice = (int) product.Price,
                           ProductQuantity = product.Quantity,
                           ProductAmount = (int) (product.Price * 
                                                  product.Quantity)
                       });
```

Comment: that's gr8 , but I got an Error as
"Explicit construction of entity type 'CartProductServiceAPI.OrderProductMapping' in query is not allowed."
any Idea what went wrong .

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the results of the `Query` like this:

```
foreach(OrderProductMapping result in Query)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: will that loop iterate just one time or more than that.
If only one time , is there any other way to pop the Element.
Basically I am from PHP background , so novice in C# working

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in Query)
{
    Console.Writeline(item.OrderId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in Query)
{
   ...
}
```

EDIT: Beaten! argh!